# Reordering rows in a UITableView

Tags: objective-c, uitableview

I've been stuck for a really long time with this problem and I need help. Here's what my code does. I have an `NSMutableArray` with data. The first row displays all the elements of the array. Then I remove the old data and add fresh data to my array. Then I display this in the second row and so on.

What I'd like to know is, how to display my data such that when I display the data for the second row, I'd like the first row to shift one row down and the second row to be displayed in the first row and so on. For example:

1st call:

> abcd (row 1)

2nd call:

> efgh (row 1) 
>   abcd (row 2)

3rd call:

> ijkl (row 1)
>
> efgh (row 2)
>
> abcd (row 3)

and so on.

Please note, a is the first element of the array, b the second, c the third and so on. It isn't a single string. I've done this for several reasons.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

In cellForRowAtIndexPath code as follows,

int index=[mutArray count]-indexPath.row-1;

[mutArray objectAtIndex:index];

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I'm not sure how this will work, because according to your suggestion this will display each element on a different row, which I don't want. I only want to be able to shift rows such that the second call to the cellForRowAtIndexPath function displays the current data on the first row and the data in the first row on the second.

Comment: Ok.  think it will work. You Just check and inform if you have any probs

Comment: Okay, but what is your code supposed to do? Doing a dry run, say the array elements are a,b,c,d and indexPath.row is 0, I'll get d as the result of [mutArray objectAtIndex:index]

Comment: Oh you want to do as follows if a,b,c,d then 1,2,3,4 means in second run it should be 1,2,3,4,a,b,c,d ?

Comment: If so you should change the logic in adding the data to array. Post that code too so that i can check and tell your problem

Comment: @KingofBliss I posted another answer that should make things a little more clear. Please have a look at it.

Answer (score 0):

Your array should contain -- let say

{ijkl,efgh,abcd}

then in the table view delegate for any row

```
int totalCount = [array count];
int startIndex = totalCount - (rowIndex+1); //rowIndex -- row index delegate is called

for(i = startIndex; i<totalCount ; i++)
{
//objectAtIndex
//display the objects from  startIndex to totalCount in the cell
}
```

Output:
row 1: 
rowIndex == 0 totalCount = 3 startIndex = 2 --> abcd

row 2: 
rowIndex == 1 totalCount = 3 startIndex = 1 --> efgh abcd

row 3: 
rowIndex == 2 totalCount = 3 startIndex = 0 --> ijkl efgh abcd

Answer (score 0):

A small clarification, the contents of my array are determined only at runtime. Each element of the array is a label. So row one will be:
label 1,label 2,label3 ...
Then the array contents are deleted and new labels are added. So now,
row 0: label 4,label5, label 6
row 1: label 1,label 2,label 3